# How getSession is called when is called from getServerSideProps?

Tags: security, next.js, next-auth

I want to show secured data only to admins. In NextAuth->callbacks->session I'm checking database if user has admin privileges and add isAdmin flag.
I don't know if this is most secured way and can anyone by doing fake request force getSession to give me wrong data.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const session = await getSession(context);
    if(session && session.isAdmin) {
       ..
```

Comment: What are you using to secure your routes?

Answer (score 1):

There is alot of ways that you could do this.

When you get the user from the database after the login you could have a field called roles or role.

For example when user goes to the protect page/pages you could do a server side validation.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }: any) {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const user = session?.user;
  if(user.role!=="admin")
  {
     custom logic or return the user to another page etc
  }
}
```